# Creating OTRS Module

Tags: javascript, module, frontend, otrs

I have create a new OTRS module but I have some issues with the Javascript files.
Actually it seems to not be executing at all.

[image]

I can send you the package file for help if necessary.

This is the .sopm file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<otrs_package version="1.0">
    <Name>Stat</Name>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Framework>5.0.19</Framework>
    <Vendor>OTRS</Vendor>
    <URL>www.otrs.org</URL>
    <License>GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3, November 2007</License>
    <ChangeLog Version="5.0.19" Date="2017-07-14 16:00:11">Init Custom Stats.</ChangeLog>
    <ChangeLog Version="5.0.19" Date="2017-07-19 09:57:11">Delete some files and change some directories.</ChangeLog>
    <Description Lang="en">Stat</Description>
    <IntroInstall Type="post" Lang="en" Title="Thank you!">Thank you for instaling this.</IntroInstall>
    <BuildDate>?</BuildDate>
    <BuildHost>?</BuildHost>
    <Filelist>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/Kernel/Config/Files/stats.xml"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/Kernel/System/CustomStats.pm"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/Kernel/Modules/AgentCustomStats.pm"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/Kernel/Language/de_CustomStats.pm"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/Kernel/Output/HTML/Templates/Standard/AgentCustomStats.tt"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/jquery.min.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/fastclick.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/jquery.flot.js"></File>
        <File Permission="666" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/jquery.flot.resize.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/jquery.flot.pie.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/jquery.flot.categories.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/customscript.js"></File>
<!--         <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/demo.js"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/js/adminlte.min.js"></File> -->
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/fonts/FontAwesome.otf"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/css/bootstrap.min.css"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/css/font-awesome.min.css"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/css/ionicons.min.css"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/css/AdminLTE.min.css"></File>
        <File Permission="755" Location="Stats/var/httpd/htdocs/css/all-skins.min.css"></File>
    </Filelist>
</otrs_package>
```

Comment: You have probably already done this, but just to be sure - have you tried clearing the cache of the OTRS and your Browser (i.e. use `Ctrl` + `F5` to reload)? This has been an issue for me in the past. Can you execute the JS Functions etc. from your developer console? (This determines if the code has actually been loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your JS files in  section in your stats.xml file (where you are register the module). Look at lines 67-75 of this https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/master/Kernel/Config/Files/Calendar.xml file as example.

Answer (score 0):

> The list of JavaScript files to be loaded is configured in the module registration setting `Loader`:

```
<FrontendModuleReg>
  ...
  <Loader>
     <JavaScript>thirdparty/flot/excanvas.js</JavaScript>
     <JavaScript>thirdparty/flot/jquery.flot.js</JavaScript>
     <JavaScript>Core.Agent.Dashboard.js</JavaScript>
  </Loader>
</FrontendModuleReg>
```